# Need to pass widget value to the Databricks SQL table location path

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to pass widget value to the Databricks SQL table location path, but getting parse exception error. Can someone share how to do it ?

**Code:**

```
%sql 
  create table if not exists CTRL.t_migration_Status (
      Run_Seq_num int,
      Table_Id varchar(10),
      Table_owner varchar(50),
      Table_Name varchar(50),
      hash_columns varchar(100),
      Load_type varchar(50),
      copy_date varchar(100),
      Source_rec_count int,
      target_Rec_count int,
      Rec_vld_status varchar(10),
      Source_hash_total int,
      Target_hash_total int,
      Hash_total_vld_Status varchar(10)
    )location "abfss://"${storage_account_containervar}"@xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/CTRL/";
```

**Error:**

```
ParseException: 
extraneous input '"@sourcesgdevops.dfs.core.windows.net/CTRL/"' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 15, pos 24)

== SQL ==
create table if not exists CTRL.t_migration_Status (
      Run_Seq_num int,
      Table_Id varchar(10),
      Table_owner varchar(50),
      Table_Name varchar(50),
      hash_columns varchar(100),
      Load_type varchar(50),
      copy_date varchar(100),
      Source_rec_count int,
      target_Rec_count int,
      Rec_vld_status varchar(10),
      Source_hash_total int,
      Target_hash_total int,
      Hash_total_vld_Status varchar(10)
    )location "abfss://""@sourcesgdevops.dfs.core.windows.net/CTRL/"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nEVt.png)

I tried to pass values , but failing with parse exception.

Answer (score 0):

> **I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results**

*Please follow below steps:*

***First create a widget. Enter your Container name inside widgets:***

```
dbutils.widgets.text("foo", "text","enter_st")
```

[image]

***Configure your storage account with Access_key.***

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net","Access_key")
```

[image]

***Now, using below code, I got these results without error.***

```
%sql
create table if not exists CTRL.t_migration_Status12 (
      Run_Seq_num int,
      Table_Id varchar(10),
      Table_owner varchar(50),
      Table_Name varchar(50),
      hash_columns varchar(100),
      Load_type varchar(50),
      copy_date varchar(100),
      Source_rec_count int,
      target_Rec_count int,
      Rec_vld_status varchar(10),
      Source_hash_total int,
      Target_hash_total int,
      Hash_total_vld_Status varchar(10)
    )location "abfss://${foo}@<Storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/dem";
```

[image]